# Format price in Danish with curency symbol on right

Tags: c#, localization, currency

How can I format a price in Eval() method for a price in Danish and with currency symbol on the right i C# ?

I have the following in my .aspx page to display the price:

```
<td class="text-right price-col"><%# Eval("Price", "{0:c}") %></td>
```

But this display the price as e.g. **kr. 79,00** .. what I want is **79,00 kr.**

I saw this post [Changing Currency Symbol location in System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446273/changing-currency-symbol-location-in-system-globalization-numberformatinfo) and added this method in codebehind which gives me the result I want:

```
<td class="text-right price-col"><%# PriceFormat(79) %></td>

protected string PriceFormat(decimal price) {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo danish = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK");
        danish = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)danish.Clone();
        // Adjust these to suit
        danish.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
        danish.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;
        decimal value = price;
        string output = value.ToString("C", danish);

        return output;
    }
```

But can I use the PriceFormat method with the Eval() method to get right price as parameter or modify the format in Eval() method to do the same?
I the example I just insert a static value as parameter (79).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval returns an `object`, so you can cast that to a `decimal` and pass it as a parameter to your `PriceFormat` method:

```
<%# PriceFormat((decimal)Eval("Price")) %>
```

Comment: Thanks :)
I moved the PriceFormat to a seperate class Common, so a can reuse the method in other files: <%# Common.PriceFormat((decimal)Eval("Price")) %>